# Localhost not working in Chrome, 127.0.0.1 does work

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

I'm trying to run a local node server, but for whatever reason `localhost:3000` does not work.  The error page states `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`  However, `127.0.0.1:3000` does work.  I have tried making changes to my hosts file, but to no avail.  Does anyone have any idea what's causing the problem?

Chrome version is 46.0.2490.80 m

Comment: This solution worked for me here: https://superuser.com/a/1423344/644358

Comment: Old post but I found the [answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1159862/when-why-would-chrome-get-500-error-on-localhost-but-load-ok-from-127-0-0-1-whi). It explains everything.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to make this work correctly:

1. Edited my hosts file so `127.0.0.1 localhost.` was present, and saved the file
2. Cleared my Chrome cache, specifically cookies and cached files
3. Cleared host cache in `chrome://net-internals/#dns`
4. Restarted chrome

Alternatively, this also works:

1. Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#hsts
2. Under "Delete domain", type `localhost` and delete

Unbeknownst to me, my project had an HSTS middleware that set an HSTS cookie

Comment: Was searching so long and had no idea what I did to cause this. For anyone coming in from Google, this happened to be by using react-aad-msal package and running a killall command on it when it froze while loading. This fixed it for me completely.

Comment: The alternative solution works for me

Comment: Alternative solution also works here

Answer (score 17):

I ran into a similar issue on my MacBook but none of the existing answers worked. I even tried the nuclear option and did a factory reset on my computer.

The issue  turned out to be coming from the AirPlay receiver listening on Ports `5000` and `7000`, which was creating the 403 error when I tried to serve something at `localhost:5000`.

The solution, as detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332), was to uncheck `AirPlay Receiver` in `System Preferences > Sharing`

Comment: This!  Thank you so much, what a weird port choice by Apple.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me considering I have a MacBook too

Comment: You're my life-saver. Thanks mate, I got the same problem in MacBookPro.

Answer (score 10):

For me (I had HTTP and HTTPs dev server on same port)

- Chrome Dev tools F12
- Application tab
- Clear storage sub-tab
- "Clear site data" button

Comment: nvm, thought it worked, still didn't

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I solved my problem by:

- opening the developer console **F12**
- Going to **network tab**
- Check **Disable Cache**
- Browse `locahost`

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked, but the the "Clear Site Data" option in the DevTools Application Tab did not. Isn't this also deleting cached site information? Anyways, thanks mate, that problem gave me regular headaches :)

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is go to Chrome `setting > Privacy` and `Settings > See all the cookies and site data`, search for localhost and delete it. Then refresh your site it will be working.

Regards

Comment: It worked for me with the opposite problem, i.e. `localhost` was working while the `127.0.0.1` address didn't.

Answer (score 4):

follow these steps.

1. open chrome
2. go to setting
3. Privacy and security
4. Clear browsing data
5. check cookies and other site data
6. click clear data.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using a proxy there's a checkbox to bypass it for local addresses.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and I cleared cookies and cache and it worked

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Setting/clearBrowserData` and just check all of history, cookies and cached files.

Answer (score 1):

For me, [Browse in Private](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) was enough.

Comment: This worked for me too (Chrome on Mac)

Answer (score -1):

**Finally I have solved this problem**

1. For those who have tried the clearing the cache from the browser and still facing the same issue follow these steps
2. search for live server(ctrl+shift+x) you will find a settings icon. click on Extension
   settings
3. you can find Live server>Settings:Chrome Debugging Attachment click on edit in Settings.json
4. just add this (if there are multiple lines make sure to add comma[,])
   `"liveServer.settings.port": 0`
5. Doing This It will randomly pick an opened port each time.