# while trying to connect to database while building backend for a project it is throwing the following error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:277:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755
err = new ServerSelectionError();
^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
address: 'localhost:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 95255416,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
at Socket. (C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\Javascript projects\tutorial\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 27017
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
},
topologyVersion: null,
setName: null,
setVersion: null,
electionId: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
primary: null,
me: null,
'$clusterTime': null
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

showing this error
how to fix it

i was trying to connect node.js to mongodb(6.0) on my windows 11 system

Comment: Can you please post the code where you handle the connection to the database?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045495/timeouterror-mongoserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.