# MongoDB doesn't connect. [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

***Note: I have already gone through the following similar threads and tried the following options:***

1. *Restarted the MongoDB service.*
2. *Replaced localhost by 0.0.0.0.*
3. *Replaced local host by 127.0.0.1:27017*

> [timeoutError - MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 - [NodeJS + MongoDB]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045495/timeouterror-mongoserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-node)

> [MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec)

> [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840504/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017)

> [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304154/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-error)

**Following is the code from index.js file:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db_c");
```

**Nodjs version:** ***v18.13.0***

**MongoDB version:** ***6.0.5***

**Mongoose version:** ***7.2.2***

**The error I am getting is:**

```
E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)   
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1981963039,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)    
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
PS E:\nodejs\app1> node index.js
E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)   
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 101790,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)       
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

PS E:\nodejs\app1> node index.js      
E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)   
    at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 945032,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs\app1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

I am an absolute beginner and seek your help.

Comment: What was the error when you tried `127.0.0.1:27017`?  How is the mongodb service configured?

Comment: Visual studio got hanged ! there was no output !

Comment: Is the MongoDB server (`mongod`) running?

Comment: Yes it is running. I also stopped it from services and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the similar connection problem with node 18.16.0. I downgraded it to 16.13.0, and it worked fine.

**Edit**:
I got it to work with node 18.16.0. There is a breaking change starting node 17 that it uses IPv6 instead of IPv4 as default. I had to modify my mongod.conf for that. The instructions are quite simple (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options). I am using node driver not mongoose. There are issues with compatibility with version of DB that I also had to work out.