# Cannot access localhost on Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, http-status-code-404

I am trying to access an application on localhost:8080.

I can access it on edge, but not on Chrome.

On chrome it shows the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I've already cleared the history and resetted the configurations of chrome to its defaults.

As suggested in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524826/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-127-0-0-1-does-work#:~:text=What%20you%20can%20do%20is,site%20it%20will%20be%20working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524826/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-127-0-0-1-does-work#:%7E:text=What%20you%20can%20do%20is,site%20it%20will%20be%20working):
I've also cleared host cache in chrome://net-internals/#dns.
Besides that I went to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and under "Delete domain", I've typed localhost and deleted it.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try a chrome incognito mode .

Comment: I've already tried an incognito window in chrome with no success.